# I want to get dates of previous week with respect to current date in php, JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to display the present week dates in a line chart on x- axis.

I need to get previous dates of a week starting from today's date. Ex. I need to get the dates as an array of values starting from 1st to 7th of a month if today is 7th.
I'm new to php and would like a simple understandable solution.
This is my js to display line chart..

```
$(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: '',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        /*subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },*/
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Total Requirements',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        },{
            name: 'Requirements with no Submissions',
            data: [1.5, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        },{
            name: 'Requirements to which Profiles were Submitted',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
```

I need the array of dates to be able to send them to categories instead of default values in them and display on x-axis.
I tried this thing but its giving me some unwanted values and also only current week if it is in middle of current week instead of moving to previous week taking 7 days into count.

```
<?php
      $dt = new DateTime();
      $dates = [];
      for ($d = 1; $d <= 6; $d++) {
      $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'),
      $dt->format('W'), $d);
      $dates[$dt->format('D')] = $dt->format('m-d-Y');
      $string=implode(",",$dates);
      echo $string;
   }
   ?>
```

My output must be 10/1 10/2 10/3 ... 10/7 if today is 7th irrespective of the week.

Comment: Can you able to show the code which you have tried

Comment: added php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this , first get today's date, than you can run a loop backward or forwards as per your needs.

**P.S:** *You need to do UTC offset etc if you are going to manage it with different timezones*.

```
     $date=date_create(DATE("d-m-Y"));

 $array=[];
 array_push($array, date_format($date,"m/j"));
    for($i=7;$i>0;$i--)
    {
     date_sub($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
     array_push($array, date_format($date,"m/j"));
    }
   echo json_encode(array_reverse($array));// or you can do echo json_encode($array) to return json
```

As per the output described by you, you will need to change the date format so change the code with

```
array_push($array, date_format($date,"m/j"));
```

and you will get the following output

```
["10\/7","10\/8","10\/9","10\/10","10\/11","10\/12","10\/13","10\/14"]
```

**Current date is  10/14**

Comment: Thanks but the date format I got was ["10\/07","10\/08","10\/09","10\/10","10\/11","10\/12","10\/13","10\/14"] instead of 10/7.

Comment: and how do I pass this to my categories array in my JS?

Comment: you will need to json by doing **json_encode** instead of **print_r** and than you can get json with ajax request of javascript or jquery to pass json to highcharts

Comment: I need  to pass each value 10/7 10/8 as values in to the array categories :['10/7','10/8','10/8'] like this.

Comment: change the date formats from m/d to m/j like this 
 array_push($array, date_format($date,"m/j"));